# UICollectionViewListCell Tap Footer & Header & UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource & SectionBackgroundDecorationView & Expand (Swift)

Tags: swift, header, footer, collectionview, expand

Welcome to the UICollectionViewListCellTapFooterHeader wiki!
The code represents the implementation of a user interface using# UIKit components in a list management application. The application displays a list of sections, where each section has an expandable header and one list item. When the user taps on the section header, it expands or collapses, revealing or hiding the list item.

In summary, the code creates a dynamic and interactive list view with expandable sections, allowing users to view and interact with different items within each section. This user interface is implemented using UICollectionView and the powerful UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource to manage the data and update the collection efficiently.

Description of Code for List Management User Interface using UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource.# [Wiki](https://github.com/SlavaLoye/UICollectionViewListCellTapFooterHeader/wiki/UICollectionViewListCell-Tap-Footer-&--Header-&-UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource-&-SectionBackgroundDecorationView-&--Expand-(Swift)) [[GitHub Project UICollectionViewListCell ->>>]](https://github.com/SlavaLoye/UICollectionViewListCellTapFooterHeader)[image]